# Image not centering in css

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I am new to html and css, i have started to make a website so i started with placing the logo and the background correctly, now the problem is that i cannot **vertically** center my logo image.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg">
        <div class="menu">          
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background:url(../img/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
    z-index:1000;
}
body {
    margin:0 ;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu { 
    background:url(../img/MenuBar.png) ;
    height:150px;
    width:1242px;
    position:relative;
}

.logo { 
    background:url(../img/Untitled-1.png) no-repeat center;
    width:262px;
    height:80px;
    margin:0 auto;  
}
```

Comment: Couple things, you have a `<div class="bg">`, but your styling is applied directly to the `body`, so you don't need it. Secondly, you don't need to separate the styles applied to `body`, they can all go together. Thirdly, `body` has a `z-index`, which won't do anything at all unless it has either `position:relative` or `position:absolute`.

Comment: ok I will correct that, but will it work afterwards?

Comment: There is no reason it shouldn't be working. Check your css sheet for things that might be impacting those `div`s. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/DKV4G/2/ It's from dwreck but without his changes. Your code is working there.

Comment: Something could be overriding your CSS that is shown here. Something could also be impacting. Do you have a declaration that forces `div`s to be `display:inline`, possibly?

Comment: No i don't think so and I have no idea why it's not centering vertically AndyM.

Comment: Just posted an answer that solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This schould do the trick.

```
.menu { 
background:url(../img/MenuBar.png) ;
height:150px;
width:1242px;
position:relative;
display: table;
```

}

```
.logo{

     background:url(../img/Untitled-1.png) no-repeat center;
     width:262px;
     height:80px;
     margin:0 auto;
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
```

}

Comment: He's already got `margin:0 auto;`, so `margin-left` and `margin-right` are meaningless repetition. The `display:block` should be already set by default with `div`, but there could be an odd CSS rule affecting, so this might work.

Comment: i have tried this, its centerning horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: Edited my answer for that, you need to use the vertical-align tag for that.

Comment: Still got three extra lines that are unneeded.

Comment: What are the extra lines AndyM?

Comment: Fixed that for you :)

Comment: He just removed them, it's good now. I'm testing in a Fiddle and it doesn't appear to be working though.

Answer (score 0):

Create a containing div using the same `"margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"` or `"margin: 0 auto"` trick you were using. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
    body{
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
    z-index:1000;
    }
    #container {
    }

    #bg {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 25%;
    }

    #menu{ 
    background-color: green;
    height:150px;
    width:600px;
    }

    #logo{
    background-color: blue;
    width:262px;
    height:80px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="bg">
        <div id="menu">          
            <div id="logo"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### What's Going On

Given that you want it work be centered vertically, the only answer here so far is to give `.menu` styling of `vertical-align:middle`. That won't work. To center vertically, you need to use a `position` trick. You give the item a `position:absolute`, then you tell it to be `top:50%`, which will place the top of that item at 50% down.

We want the center of the item to be in the center of the container though, not the top to be at the center. So we finally add `margin-top` of a negative value. That negative value is half the object's height, in this case, `80px` / 2 = `40px`. To center horizontally, we'll need to do the same. `margin:0 auto` won't work now given that it's positioned absolutely.

### Code

In the end, you will change this:

```
.logo { 
    background:url(../img/Untitled-1.png) no-repeat center;
    width:262px;
    height:80px;
    margin:0 auto;  
}
```

To this:

```
.logo {
    background:url(../img/Untitled-1.png) no-repeat center;
    width:262px;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-40px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-131px;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DKV4G/5/)

Comment: Great ! but will the display be the same in all the browsers and different screen resolutions?

Comment: Depends what you mean by the same. The container `.menu` is a fixed width object. That means that it isn't responsive and won't change. On smaller screens, you will get horizontal scrollbars. However, the logo will always, no matter the screen size, be centered inside `.menu`. You can even, if you like, change `.menu` to be flexible, and the above code will still work.

Comment: Is there a reason you selected and then unselected this as the answer?

Comment: No no reason ! it works fine too!! if i could select 2 answers i will choose yours too!

Comment: Fair enough. General policy is that you upvote all correct and helpful answers (including the checkmarked answer), and select the one that you actually use, or think is best, to give the checkmark. This provides incentive to those who try to help out, and makes it easier for future readers to see which answers are useful.